# Sending messages from background thread to main thread on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, multithreading

I have an iOS app where I am completing tasks on the background thread. As each task is completed I want to send a message to the main thread so I can move along my custom progress bar to the appropriate stage.

What is the simplest, yet most secure way to achieve this?

**EDIT 1**

This is the method I am using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {

     // get background tasks done. 
     [self.background backgroundMethod];

});
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is an example of what I would attempt using @Madboy's answer. Within the class where I perform methods in the background I have a pointer to my progress bar.  Do we think this would work? **(Please note the change also to EDIT 1).**

```
@implementation BackgroundClass
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize customProgressBar

- (void)backgroundMethod
{
    // Run tasks
}

- (void)delegateSaysBackgroundMethodIsFinished
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(tasksDone:) withObject:self.customProgressBar waitUntilDone:NO];

}

@implementation CustomProgressBar

- (void)tasksDone
{
    // change UI to reflect progress done. 
}
```

Comment: As you are using dispatch_async(), have a look at my answer that also uses dispatch_async() as this would be the preferred way.

Answer (score 10):

This is based on what you are doing. Are you performing tasks in the background with GCD? Then you simply can call:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //your main thread task here
});
```

If you are running in an NSThread you could do this:

```
[myObject performSelectorOnMainThread:YOURSELECTOR withObject:YOUROBJECT waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: Where on the main thread will this run? Will it be within the Class and method where the original background thread was called?

Comment: This will be executed at the end of the current runloop or at the beginning of the next run loop, depending on when you call these methods. All you do from another thread can not be executed in the original method itself, as this is already gone and not on the stack anymore! >> note my changes above, I picked the wrong method for the NSThread stuff, as I don't use this...

Comment: Thanks for the effort. If you have a moment could you take a glance at my EDIT 2 and let me know what you think?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` method of [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

The waitUntilDone parameter is a bool. You can pass YES to make your background thread wait until the method on main thread is done. You can pass NO to just fire that method and continue execution on background thread simultaneously with the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

`NSNotificationCenter` allows messaging between threads. You set up a 'listener' and can then broadcast notifications - the Apple documentation is very good, and it's easy to pick up.

Comment: Note that notifications get dispatched in the thread they were created! So you still need to change the thread by yourself!