# How do I use GCD to do something on the main thread immediately?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, ipad

i have some code that is running on the main thread, as well as a secondary GCD thread which is processing some data.  After the data is processed, i need to update the UI and preferably as soon as possible, so is it possible for me to move that to the main thread to be processed immediately? Thanks!

Comment: What you have tried? It is not very difficult you can easily find answer on internet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905192/iphone-grand-central-dispatch-main-thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933397/sending-messages-from-background-thread-to-main-thread-on-ios

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502242/ios-how-to-get-background-thread-to-redraw-view-on-main-thread

Answer (score 0):

```
void es_dispatch_sync_on_main_thread(dispatch_block_t block)
{
        if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                block();
        } else {
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
        }
}
```